# How to do a multi-tile plot with layout

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot four of the following in an `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`..

```
layout(matrix(1:2,ncol=1),widths=1,heights=c(2,2),respect=FALSE)
par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="Hi",type='l',ylab='',xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="",xlab="Hi",type='l',ylab='')
```

Therefore what I'm looking for is a total of 8 plots; 4 tiles of the above double plot. Yet if I precede the above with par(mfrow=c(2,2)) and run the above four times, it will simply generate a new plot each time, overwriting the call to `mfrow`.

How can I adjust the above code such that it works with `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`?

Comment: ?layout is "totally incompatible with the other mechanisms for arranging plots on a device", use one or the other

Answer (score 2):

Use directly a proper `layout`, you don't need to cumulate it with `par(mfrow=...)`.

```
layout(matrix(1:8,ncol=2))
par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="Hi1",type='l',ylab='',xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="",xlab="Hi1",type='l',ylab='')

par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="Hi2",type='l',ylab='',xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="",xlab="Hi2",type='l',ylab='')

par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="Hi3",type='l',ylab='',xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="",xlab="Hi3",type='l',ylab='')

par(mar = c(0, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="Hi4",type='l',ylab='',xaxt='n')
par(mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
plot(rnorm(100),main="",xlab="Hi4",type='l',ylab='')
```

[image]

As you see on the picture above, the order of plotting if the same as the order of the matrix used to define the layout:

```
matrix(1:8,ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4    8
```